# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL after I click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, button

I having this issue and when i inspect this error shows up "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" whenever after i click the cancel button and the button does nothing. all other buttons works fine except for this cancel button.

the javascript

```
  function showEditBox(editobj,id) {
    $('#frmAdd').hide();
    $(editobj).prop('enabled','true');
    var currentMessage = $("#message_" + id + " .message-content").html();
    var editMarkUp = '<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" cols="80" id="txtmessage_'+id+'">'+currentMessage+'</textarea><button name="ok" onClick="callCrudAction(\'edit\','+id+')">Save</button><button name="cancel" onClick="cancelEdit(\''+currentMessage+'\','+id+')">Cancel</button>';
    $("#message_" + id + " .message-content").html(editMarkUp);
  }
```

the error show line 1 but there are nothing other than a html tag.
Anyone can help me see whats the problem?

Comment: You may have some invisible unicode glyphs in there, like a zero-width space. There's nothing in the code you posted here however.

Comment: anyway i can check it?

Comment: On Linux you can use `od -c` to dump out the file contents. Or you can try re-typing parts of the source file. The weird characters generally are a result of cutting/pasting from some online source, or from a Word document or something like that.

Comment: Is it proper to pass an object in a jquery selector?

Comment: @Popatop15 do you have any other suggestion to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure. I didn't know it was even possible to pass and object as a jquery selector